# How to Split a Recorded video in part for editing?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, video

I want to get a video of last 4 second of 10 second video. I have no idea how to do this task.
Please guide me .How to split video into small part on the basis of time duration.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my suggestion, please follow one by one:

- get a [free simple video editor](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4233/simple-video-editing-tool/9384#9384) with split function as well as
  zoom in/out function, which is the indispensable function for you to
  edit short video clips.
- import your recorded video and drag it to timeline, which will look like short and hard to edit normally if your video only lasts 10 seconds
- use zoom in function, which can extend your video to details and it helps you to split video precisely.
- then move the indicator in timeline to the point you want to split, click the split button, which will be always designed as a scissor.
- click the part you don't want and then move it to trash box or click delete button.
- last step, export this video, done.